# Change Resolution on ubuntu 16.04 32 bit not working

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution

I am on ubuntu 16.04 now, i had upgraded from 14.04 32 bit. I only can set a resolution of 1024x768 or 800x600, but on ubuntu 14.04 I could set a better resolution. What can I do? I have tried to do it in the grub.conf file to set there a better resolution, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved now! I am so happy now, resolution of 1280x800 works now. The problem was that the video card i use is very old. I found instructions to add a boot parameter. The line looked before adding like this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset". I erased nomodeset and wrote "quiet splash raedon.dpm=1" and did a reboot. After that everything is like it should. Hope that helps somebody with an old Raedon Video card. Best Regards